# How can Scheme's Map function be used to pass two lists to a single function?

Tags: list, dictionary, scheme, fold, arity

I have a question about Scheme.  I am fairly new to the language, and my question is fairly general:

Is it possible, without defining a recursive function, to use Map (or something like it) to feed two lists of parameters into a function, producing a single new list from the outputs?

For instance, suppose I had:

```
(define lst1 (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(define lst2 (list 2 4 6 8 10))
```

And I wanted to then somehow map the + function, supplying each list as a parameter such that the output would be a new list, lst3:

```
>lst3
(3 6 9 12 15)
```

To state the question somewhat more succinctly: how might one *most efficiently* map a binary function when both parameters are lists?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(map + lst1 lst2)
```

MAP can take any number of lists.

Example:

```
(map + lst1 lst2 lst1) => (4 8 12 16 20)
```

Comment: Doh, I feel really stupid!  Thanks for taking the time to answer.